# Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path

Tags: java, android, macos, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to set up react-native (for Android) on my macOs but the app is failing to build so I am retrying it by following this link:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

In one of the steps, we have to add something to our `$HOME/.bash_profile`. I open it using `vi .bash_profile` and then paste the commands. Next, I am asked to **'Verify that ANDROID_HOME has been added to your path by running `echo $PATH.`'**

When I run `echo $PATH.`, I get this:

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users//Library/Android/sdk/emulator:/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users//Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

I don't see the word ANDROID_HOME anywhere. Is there a problem here? Maybe with the path? Or is it being correctly verified?

I am running this in the root directory.

**EDIT:**

I managed to successfully setup everything and run the default AwesomeProject as well (from the root directory). However, when I try to run another project, it does not work. I see this:

SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/mycompany/insta/app/android/local.properties

What's the problem? Which steps from the setup should I repeat inside this particular folder? Should I make another bash profile? I don't get what path to add in the local.properties

Comment: can you verify that the ANDROID_HOME is set in your system variables and also does it point to the android SDK path?

Answer (score 0):

Your `PATH` variable is being correctly modified.

Echo your `ANDROID_HOME` variable to see what it is. It should be `/Users//Library/Android/sdk/`. When you use this variable in `PATH`, it's automatically being expanded when you echo it. You won't see "ANDROID_HOME" in the PATH.

Comment: I don't see anything when I echo this variable. From what I observed, all previous steps were successful. Then which part am I missing out on? I have already done everything from the ```2. Install the Android SDK``` steps on the link.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. In your bash profile, do you have `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk`? The next line is `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator`, which you do have in your PATH: `/Users//Library/Android/sdk/emulator`, you can see how that directory is a combination of the variables. If the second thing works (which it obviously does), I don't see how the first thing would be wrong since the second depends on the first. The PATH variable is what your tutorial wanted it to be. You do appear to have an extra `/`, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the environment variable documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables

According to the dev website:

> If ANDROID_HOME is defined and contains a valid SDK installation, its value is used  instead of the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT.

> If ANDROID_HOME is not defined, the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is used.

> If ANDROID_HOME is defined but does not exist or does not contain a valid SDK
> installation, the value in ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is used instead.

Try `echo $ANDROID_HOME`. If that returns nothing try `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`. One of them should return your SDK directory. If not export one of them in your `bash_profile` as a env variable.

Easiest solution is to do a quick install of Android Studio and selecting the option to install SDK tools. This easily sets up your environment for android. All you need to do is add the SDK tools directory to your path once the install completes.

AVD images are pedantic if you change any directories and throw SDK_ROOT errors if you change things. Most problem free solution is to either download and run the installer or download the SDK tools, run the install and specify the path directory.

Comment: I don't see anything when I echo either of these variables. From what I observed, all previous steps were successful. Then which part am I missing out on?

Comment: I have already done everything from the ```2. Install the Android SDK``` steps on the link.

Comment: In the link you provided it seems they manually set their ANDROID_HOME environment variable. 

So if you go into your `bash_profile or .bashrc` and put `export ANDROID_HOME=/PATH2SDK/`. Where PATH2SDK is the directory of your android sdk. 

Restart the terminal and try `echo $ANDROID_HOME` and it should give it back to you.

Comment: Edit your `bash_profile` and put `export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/PATH2SDK/`. 

If it still throws errors try reinstalling android studio. When it prompts for SDK download path just select your SDK and it will autoconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

create `local.properties` file inside android folder and paste `sdk.dir={ANDROID_SDK_PATH}`, then restart react-native server.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has to do with two things:

1. local.properties file
2. ANDROID_HOME (SDK path)

Firstly,
For the local.properties, first make sure that the file is there in your project folder/android. If the file is there open it and make sure that the `sdk.dir` is pointing to your android SDK directory.

and if the file is not there create it and paste this:

```
sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Replace `USERNAME` with your username

Secondly,
make sure that the `ANDROID_HOME` is there in the system variables and is also pointing to your android SDK directory.

or create new system variable named `ANDROID_HOME` and set the value your android SDK directory path if it's not there